# ensuring line break after nth word

Tags: php, regex

i have below script which converts the text into image but the problem is it breaks after nth character and ignores words so the final output is confusing.

i am able to ensure the first line to end with word but i want the same for all lines so that every line ends with word and new line starts with next word.here is my code

```
   <?php
  $fileName = 'test.png';
  $img_width = 800;
  $img_height = 90;
  $font = 'Parisish.ttf';    
  $string = 'Tujhse doori ka ehsas satane laga,
    Tere sath gujra har lamha yaad aane laga,
 Jab bhi koshish ki tujhe bhulne ki ae mere hamdum…
     Tu aur jyada dil ke kareeb aane laga…';
   $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8',"UTF-8");

 $curstringLen = strlen($string);
  $limit = 40;
  $totalLine = ceil($curstringLen / $limit);
  $img_height = $img_height * $totalLine;

  $im = imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);
   $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
  $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

  imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, $white);

  for($i = 1; $i <= $totalLine; $i++){


   $y = $i * 70;

    $stringN = substr($string,($limit * ($i-1)),strpos($string, ' ', $limit));



   imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 50, $y, $grey, $font,mb_convert_encoding($stringN, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'));
      imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 51, $y, $black, $font,mb_convert_encoding($stringN, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'));
  }
   imagepng($im, $fileName); 
 ?>
```

it works but give output for only english character and breaks line at the limit without considering words